# How can i call .NET web service from PHP

Tags: c#, php, .net, web-services

The .NET web service code

```
[WebMethod]
public string asd(){
    return "asd";
}
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php
require 'lib/nusoap.php';

$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/nos/WebSite/Service.asmx?WSDL");

$error = $client->getError();
if ($error) {
    die("client construction error: {$error}\n");
}

$answer = $client->call('asd');
print $answer;
$error = $client->getError();
?>
```

I searched a lot and applied everything but my code doesn't work, it only shows a white page.

Comment: What does your `Web.config` look like?

Comment: sorry i can't understand what u saying clearly

Comment: What problems are you running into?